# Stress in the -ing form of verbs with initial-stress-derived nouns

Tags: verbs, nouns, pronunciation, gerunds, stress

It seems some verbs change the stressed syllable in the -ing form:

- proCESS -- PROcessing
- transPORT -- TRANsporting

and some do not:

- diRECT -- diRECTing
- proVIDE -- proVIDing

Is this related with that the verbs of the first group have initial-stress-derived nouns? Or, what is the rule?

Comment: The stress in the verb *process* normally falls on its first syllable, not its second. And it is hardly uncommon to hear the verb *transport* with initial stress.

Comment: Are you asking about British à english or American English?  The two dialects differ on this very point.

Comment: It's English...

Comment: @Tuffy I would be interested in both, British and American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only rule about stress for the *-ing* form of a verb is that it falls in the same place as in the other forms of the verb.

The verbs that you mention don't actually change their stressed syllable in the *-ing* form.

*Procéss* and *prócess* are two different verbs with different meanings: *procéss* has a meaning like "to move in a procession" and *prócess* has a meaning like "to change something for some purpose". Their *-ing* forms are *procéssing* and  *prócessing* respectively. The *-ing* form *procéssing* is probably more often encountered as present participle ("They were procéssing down the street") than as a gerund, since the noun *procéssion* is used to refer to the action of *procéssing.* (In fact, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, the verb *procéss* is derived from the noun *procéssion*.) The *-ing* form *prócessing* has the same form as a commonly used deverbal noun *prócessing.*

*Transport* is one verb with two pronunciations: *tránsport* and *transpórt.* Either pronunciation can be used in any of the forms of the verb, so both *tránsporting* and *transpórting* exist, as well as *tránsported* and *transpórted*. The pronunciation  of the verb as *tránsport* may be due to influence from the noun *tránsport,* but it can be used in any form of the verb, not just the *-ing* form. Another verb that can have the stress placed on either syllable with no difference in meaning is *transfer.*

Comment: I was thinking of the procession of the equinoxes.

Comment: @tchrist: usually we talk about the equinoxes *precessing*, not *processing* (although in fact they do both).

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh: Yes, that's exactly so. Here's a Youtube clip with an example of the stress pattern transpórting: https://youtu.be/-gUnAF9xFnQ?t=78